# Instagram Api and authentication

Tags: instagram-api

I want to make something like an instagram web viewer like http://www.imgrum.org

Now, when I open https://www.instagram.com/developer/

I see that instagram requires some authentication from every user to access their images, but I have never authorized imgrum, yet my images etc. are visible on imgrum.org. How are they doing it? Or am I misinterpreting instragram API documentation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need authentication from a specific user to access that specific user's **public** content via the API.

In order to access **public** Instagram content via the API, you just need to authenticate any single Instagram account.

Once you authenticate any Instagram account, you can, through the access token for that account, access most of the public Instagram content.

***As a concrete example, here are 2 GET requests you can make with a single user access token:***

1) Request recent images of the user whose access token you have.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/self/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Note here the `self`: meaning the user whose access token is `ACCESS-TOKEN`.

2) Request recent images of any other user on Instagram with a public account.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/users/{user-id}/media/recent/?access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN
```

Note here the `{user-id}` in place of `self`: meaning you can enter any `user-id` for any public Instagram account. And also note that this request still requires an `ACCESS-TOKEN`, but that the user associated with the `ACCESS-TOKEN` does not have to be the same user associated with `user-id`.

This is all documented here:
https://www.instagram.com/developer/endpoints/users/

https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/

**Update:**

In order to make the 2nd API call I listed above to any {user-id}, you need the ACCESS-TOKEN (of the authenticated user) to include public-content as part of the scope. In order to get that, your app must be approved by Instagram.

Comment: Hi Sam, can you help me to conclude my instagram authentication? i'm trying in every way till more hours without result. I'm arrived on Step Two, i have code https://www.instagram.com/developer/authentication/, but i don't know how go on to request access code, isn't very clear for me instagram guide about endpoints step.

i hope you can give me some suggestions.
Thank you.
Regards

Comment: Are you doing client-side (implicit) authentication or server-side (explicit) flow?

Comment: If you are doing client-side (implicit) authentication, then on step 2 instagram will redirect the client to your url via this link `http://your-redirect-uri#access_token=ACCESS-TOKEN`. The stuff after the `#` symbol is called a fragment identifier and you can grab it using javascript: `window.location.hash.substr(1);`. Hope that helps.